# On fling to cause a simple animation

Tags: java, android, animation

I am not sure how to make a simple onFling simply start an animation. It doesnt matter which direction the swipes go any contact and slide across the screen should cause the animation to start. The other thing I am wondering is how to get it to let the animation run through and when the animation finishes I want it to display a picture. To give you an idea of what I am doing picture a twister spin board. The animation is the spinner spinning and after it finishes spinning it stops and points in a direction. How can I get a similar effect. (The animation is a spinning animation and the pictures are all pointing in differnt directions)

Would appreciate any help anyone can give. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

one possibility: use a gesturedetector to detect the fling.

psuedocode:

```
public class WhatEver extends Activity implements OnGestureListener {
private GestureDetector gestures;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
gestures = new GestureDetector(mContext, this);
View yourViewYouWantToHaveThemFling=(View) findViewById(blah..);
yourViewYouWantToHaveThemFling.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {

                    if (gestures.onTouchEvent(event)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }

            });

}
//all your normal stuff
@Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {

        return true; //must return true to continue
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {
//do something
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX,

            float distanceY) {

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {

        return false;
    }
}
```

as for the animation, set a listener on your animation,

```
yourAnimation.setAnimationListener(new DisplayPicture());
```

then

```
private final class DisplayPicture implements Animation.AnimationListener {
.
.

public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            //code to display your picture here
        }
.
.
}
```